# Manually insert TURN users (Coturn) into a database

Tags: stun, turn, coturn

I'm trying to set up a TURN server for a project using Coturn but am finding that documentation is sketchy at best...

I realise that there is a `turnadmin` tool that will do this for you, but I would greatly prefer to just run queries on my database directly. This is an app with potentially many users and their shared keys (`hmackey` in `turnusers_lt`) are subject to change (in order to not share passwords with the app the app uses a 'fake' password which is a hash of certain volatile user parameters that aren't so secret).

I can gather from the scant docs that the `hmackey` is computed using the realm, username and password:

```
$ turnadmin -k -u myusername -r my.realm.org -p my-password
> e.g. 0x7a69b0e2b747a4560045f79d171b78c0
```

Given that my code will know these three parameters, how do I build the hmac hash? E.g. in PHP I have

```
string hash_hmac ( string $algo , string $data , string $key [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
```

`$algo` here should be SHA1, but what values would go into `$data` (e.g. concat of user/pass) and `$key` (e.g. realm)?

There's also a `turn_secret` table listing a 'value' for a realm, I was guessing this should be used as the `$key` in the above example, but adding and modifying the keys still give the same result when I call turnadmin.

Essentially, what I want to do is (pseudo-code):

```
// user registers
// pseudo-code, this is of course computed using php's password_hash function
$hashed_pw = hash($pw);
$db->query('insert into usertable (name, pass) values ($name, $hashed_pw)');

// this is implemented somewhere...
$coturn_pw = get_secret_hash($name);

// this needs implementing...
$HAMC = calc_hmac($name, $coturn_pw, 'my.realm.com');

$turndb->query('insert into turnusers_lt values (...)');

// on update, delete also update turnusers_lt
```

...and then in the client, I should now be able to connect to the TURN server using `$name` and `$coturn_pw` as credentials for `my.realm.com`.

Or am I over-thinking this and should I just use a generic user for my app, hardcode the password and let Coturn figure out who is talking to who?

Answer (score 2):

How to build the HMAC key is described in [RFC 5389](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389#section-15.4):

> key = MD5(username ":" realm ":" SASLprep(password))
>
> where MD5 is defined in [RFC 1321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321) and SASLprep() is defined in [RFC 4013](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4013)

The only table you need to update is `turnusers_lt`. The `turn_secret` table and SHA1 algorithm is used for generating [time-limited credentials](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/blob/4.5.0.6/README.turnserver#L171).

```
INSERT INTO turnusers_lt (realm, name, hmackey) VALUES (:realm, :username, :key);
```

And of course, use prepared statements rather than building the SQL string manually.

Answer (score 2):

OrangeDog answer is correct.

With node.js:

```
const crypto= require("crypto");

const username= "foo";
const realm= "here";
const password= "secret";

const hmac = crypto
        .createHash("md5")
        .update(`${username}:${realm}:${password}`)
        .digest("hex")
;
```